# Android app with traditional and SL4A portions

Tags: java, android, python, sl4a

I am looking to integrate two components that currently work. One is a traditional java android app, and the other is a python script. I have the python one working just fine in SL4A, and I am looking to basically call the python script from my Java based android app and process the output in my app.

**TL;DR: Is there a way for me to call a python script from an android app and get the output?**

Comment: did you worked this out?

Comment: Its been a while, but I seem to remember diving into a lot of java in this instance... so I don't think I did.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no experience with it personally, I have read that [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) can handle running python script on Android.

Comment: Kivy wouldn't work because it would require that I redevelop the java portion. I am basically trying to tie two working components together without doing a rewrite. I havent been given that kind of time at work.

Comment: Ah, okay, good to know for the future.  Sorry that didn't work out- good luck finding a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AIDE+sl4a to create apk files, but them will require Python library: [link](http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2012/07/31/how-to-create-an-android-app-and-apk-on-android-with-python/)